# I have created aws Code build for .Net project, it is working correctly but not generating any output, How can I get output for this code build?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have this project in .net, Repository is in GIT, I have defined code build, its building project without any issue, but it is not generating any output ? where can I find output which I can deploy to AWS lambda ? following is my yml for build.
version: 0.2

```
#env:
  #variables:
     # key: "value"
     # key: "value"
  #parameter-store:
     # key: "value"
     # key: "value"
  #git-credential-helper: yes

phases:
  install:
    #If you use the Ubuntu standard image 2.0 or later, you must specify runtime-versions.
    #If you specify runtime-versions and use an image other than Ubuntu standard image 2.0, the build fails.
    runtime-versions:
       dotnet: 2.2
      # name: version
    #commands:
      # - command
      # - command
  #pre_build:
    #commands:
      # - command
      # - command
  build:
    commands:
      dotnet build GoTaskmeAPI_AWS.sln  --configuration  Release
      # - command
  #post_build:
    #commands:
      # - command
      # - command
#artifacts:
# files:
 #   - /*
    # - location
  #name: $(date +%Y-%m-%d)
  #discard-paths: yes
  #base-directory: location
#cache:
  #paths:
    # - paths
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the Build Logs? If yes, then it seems you haven't enabled CloudWatch logs for the build project.

Under your build project, go to Edit > Logs, then check the box "CloudWatch logs - optional". Run the build again and see if this helps. I am assuming the CodeBuild Service role already has the required permissions to write to CloudWatch.

Comment: No, I mean output libraries/ executables/dlls

Comment: When you run the "dotnet build" command in, say, your laptop, where is the output generated? You will find it in similar directory structure in CodeBuild. You will need to export these files via 'artifacts' construct in buildspec file.

Comment: yes that the thing, I am not able to find those directories.

Comment: Can you help me to construct build spec file ? How do I export those results ?

Comment: You will need to confirm the location of output artifact produced first, a trick is to install 'tree' in the Install phase and run 'tree .' in post_build phase to see the tree hierarchy of the working directory to confirm the location of artifacts produced.